# Most common week days query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Have this query:

```
SELECT HOUR( DATE ) AS hr, COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY hr
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

DATE is a DATETIME field and the above query shows me the most common hours in the date field.

I'm trying to improve it but not sure how to do it, I want to break it down by week days and within each week day to most common hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  DAYOFWEEK(DATE) AS wd,
  HOUR(DATE) AS hr,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
 users
GROUP BY
  wd, hr
ORDER BY
  cnt DESC
```

---

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a') AS wd, -- or DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%W')
  HOUR(DATE) AS hr,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
 users
GROUP BY
  wd, hr
ORDER BY
  cnt DESC
```

Comment: Works great!, how can I know if first day number 1 is Sunday or Monday?

Comment: DAYOFWEEK always returns 1 = Sunday, and so on.

Comment: You can use DATE_FORMAT function, e.g. - DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a')

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if below works:

```
SELECT dayname(DATE) as week_day,HOUR( DATE ) AS hr, COUNT( * ) AS cnt 
FROM users 
GROUP BY week_day, hr ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: This gave me more results than I was expecting (did work though). I'm looking for a breakdown of: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat and then within that the most common hours.

Comment: Then try with changing order of column in group by